# Use PHP to delete lines from a .txt file based on time 2

Tags: php, unix, time, code-snippets

Ok, Ive had a question on this before.

I found out how to delete lines in a txt file using php based on unix time

this is my current code.

```
<?php
$output = array();
$lines = file('file.txt');
$now = time();

foreach ($lines as $line) {
  list($content, $time) = explode("|", $line);
  if ($time > $now) {
 $output[] = $line;
 }
 }
 $outstring = implode($output);
file_put_contents("file.txt", $outstring);
print time();
?>
```

What that code does is every entry in the file will have a time next to it in Unix

So

Its set up like this

```
Content | Unix Time
Content | Unix Time
```

What I Want to do is Have a PHRASE or WORD In replace of the unix time, that indicates that line needs to stay there.

Is there a snippet or would this be hard?

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
$keepStr = "KEEP";
```

at the top and replacing the `foreach` loop with:

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    list($content, $value) = explode("|", $line);
    if ($value == $keepStr || $value > time() ) {
       $output[] = $line;
    }
}
```

would convert

```
Content1 | KEEP
Content2 | Somevalue
Content3 | Someothervalue
Content4 | KEEP
```

To

```
Content1 | KEEP
Content4 | KEEP
```

You can define the string to keep as whatever you like by changing the value given to `$keepStr`

Comment: I Want there to be a a phrase that keeps the ones with that word.

But Still Deletes the other ones if the Unix Time Has Elapsed

Answer (score 1):

Take a look and what I posted at your post before (for reference). You could easily do this by changing the condition in the `if` statement. (Same goes for other solutions, look at what I've changed in the `if` statement).

Using the code I posted before with a few modifications:

```
<?php
$whiteword = "keep";
$filtered = array();
if($handle = fopen("file.txt", "r")){
    while($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, "|")){
        if($data[1] === $whiteword || $data[1] > time()){
            $filtered[] = $data;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
if($handle = fopen("file.txt", "w")){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($filtered); $i += 1){
        fputcsv($handle, $filtered[$i], "|");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @Ron so does the code that you marked as an answer in the original question.

Comment: @Ron It sure does... `file_put_contents`: "... the existing file is overwritten". Both overwrite the file, but are you saying that my program deleted EVERYTHING in the file?

Comment: Please - does it **delete** everything? *Both* will **overwrite** the file, because that's what the function does. But does it **delete** everything? I don't want to hear you say "overwrite" again.

Comment: When I Executed your Code, It removed everything. the file was empty.

Comment: @Ron Okay, I see. Go back to the original question that you asked and try that code - make sure it doesn't delete everything/empty the file.